# Laravel Policy. Авторизация действий пользователя на работу с отдельными полями Eloquent модели

Tags: laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как правильно через политики запретить/разрешить например обновление конкретного поля модели. Сделать отдельный метод для каждого поля или какой то универсальный метод, где нужное разрешение будет передаваться в качестве аргумент?

Например у меня модель `User` связана с моделью `Permission` через `many2many`, так что я могу получить связанные с пользователем разрешения и проверить наличие нужных разрешений у пользователя. У меня есть модель `Invoice` доступ к методам CRUD, которого валидируется через политики, но при обновлении мне нужно проверять у некоторых полей наличие у пользователя нужного разрешения, например `payment_status` и при отсутствии нужного разрешения просто не обновлять это поле. И я немного непониманию как правильно использовать тут политики, и зачем это мне нужно если я могу в модели пользователя просто сделать метод, который будет проверять мне у пользователя нужное мне разрешение и для этого не нужно будет писать отдельные методы и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> И я немного непониманию как правильно использовать тут политики, и зачем это мне нужно если я могу в модели пользователя просто сделать метод, который будет проверять мне у пользователя нужное мне разрешение и для этого не нужно будет писать отдельные методы и т.д.

Я так понимаю, вы хотите переместить проверку из политик в сущность пользователя? Вы можете делать все, что вам угодно. Вы просто перемещаете методы из одного места в другое. Но, этим самым вы создаете так называемый `God Object` (считается плохим дизайном). Поэтому принято это все разделять на отдельные части. Вам будет самому приятнее возвращаться в проект спустя некоторое время.

В вашем случае, т.к. у вас есть проверки на уровне полей, то вам нужно создать [кастомные правила валидации](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) этих полей. А там уже вызывайте ваши политики, гейты  или другие ваши правила.